# Is it possible to bypass the ShadowDOM polyfill in Dart?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Is it possible to bypass platform.js when using it in dart?

This is an example:

```
  final style = new dom.StyleElement()..text = css;
  dom.document.head.append(style);
  style.sheet.cssRules; //this is List<CssRule>
```

If however I add platform.js and dart_support.js from the web_components package I get:

```
  final style = new dom.StyleElement()..text = css;
  dom.document.head.append(style);
  style.sheet.cssRules; //this is UnknownJavaScriptObject
```

It looks like element wrapping causes it. Is there a way to unwrap a dart dom element to fix this problem?